# Windows Form not loading

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created a windows form design and here is the auto-generated code

[image]

```
{...}
    '
    'PosEmea17_2
    '
    Me.AcceptButton = Me.rapportGenerieren
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.AutoSize = True
    Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(448, 219)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.rapportGenerieren)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.bis2)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.bis1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label6)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.von2)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.von1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label5)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label3)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label4)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.MinimizeBox = False
    Me.Name = "PosEmea17_2"
    Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    Me.Text = "Pos EMEA"
    Me.TopMost = True
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

{...}
```

Here the call of the form

```
Public Sub CreateFormWith2DateRange()
    Dim oFormPosEmea As PosEmea17_2 = New PosEmea17_2
    oFormPosEmea.Show()

End Sub
```

When I'm calling this form he's hanging in the middle of the screen like he wasn't loaded.

**EDIT**

After putting a new constructor the form is displayed but the labels are not loaded.

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Wenn using ShowDialog() the form is displayed and works but wenn I move it the update of the screen is laggy

Comment: If you can see it "hanging in the middle of the screen" then it loaded.  Maybe describe the problem better and if you have code in the load event, show that.  The designer code is unlikely to be at fault

Comment: Does your application freeze, or is the window still movable but without any controls? Make sure that `InitializeComponent()` is called in every existing constructor.

Comment: The load code is empty.
If you want I have something in the taskbar and I see a square on the screen "working" but nothing is displayed

Comment: Probably you have a constructor `New` which doesn't call `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: Edit after adding new constructor

Comment: Parts of the UI are simply unpainted, you can see the window behind it peeking through.  Use Task Manager to look at what your program is doing, it is likely to be burning 100% core.  Use Debug > Break All repeatedly to have some idea where that bad code is located.

Comment: Nothing to break as the winform get direclty in "not responding" in the task manager

Comment: Do you have a custom [**`Paint` event handler**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) somewhere, or perhaps an infinite loop? I'd follow Hans's suggestion and use the debugger to break execution. It'll show you what part of your program it is currently running, giving you a hint of where the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

Finally my problem was related to the fact I was creating my form in the middle of "SAP". Should have used SAP built in functions.